# WCF expected to find node type Element with name

Tags: c#, wcf, soap

Given this WSDL:
[Adyen notification WSDL](https://ca-test.adyen.com/ca/services/Notification?wsdl)
And this svcutil command to create the corresponding C# class:

```
svcutil.exe https://ca-test.adyen.com/ca/services/Notification?wsdl /t:code /l:c# /o:"C:\NotificationRequest.cs" /ct:System.Collections.Generic.List`1
```

And the OperationContract:

```
[OperationContract(Action="http://notification.services.adyen.com/sendNotification")]  
string SendNotification(NotificationRequest notificationRequest);
```

Calling the SendNotification method (SOAP) works with WCFStorm.
But when I call the method via the Third Party website, which has a test button, I get:

> OperationFormatter encountered an invalid Message body. Expected to find node type 'Element' with name 'SendNotification' and namespace 'http://tempuri.org/'. Found node type 'Element' with name 'ns1:sendNotification' and namespace 'http://notification.services.adyen.com'

This is the part of the Third Party request call that gives me the problem:

```
<soap:Body><ns1:sendNotification xmlns:ns1="http://notification.services.adyen.com"><ns1:notification>
```

How can I fix this with, preferably, some small C# attribute directives?

**UPDATE**
Fixed the 'http://tempuri.org/'-part of the problem by adding a namespace to the *IPSPNotificationService* ServiceContract:

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://notification.services.adyen.com")]
public interface IPSPNotificationService
```

**UPDATE 2**
By changing the OperationContract WCFStorm still works fine. Now the method is also fired by the Third Party call, but the NotificationRequest param, in this case, is NULL:

```
[OperationContract(Action="http://notification.services.adyen.com/sendNotification", Name="sendNotification")]
string SendNotification(NotificationRequest notificationRequest);
```

**UPDATE 3**
Let's look at it in a simpler way. Given the xml below, what contract/service decorations do I need?

```
<E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent">
    <System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system">
        <EventID>0</EventID>
        <Type>3</Type>
        <SubType Name="Information">0</SubType>
        <Level>8</Level>
        <TimeCreated SystemTime="2016-03-08T10:27:30.7325676Z" />
        <Source Name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging" />
        <Correlation ActivityID="{742fac90-3b97-4c9f-aee3-fd2589f75c37}" />
        <Execution ProcessName="obscured" ProcessID="13280" ThreadID="11" />
        <Channel />
        <Computer>obscured</Computer>
    </System>
    <ApplicationData>
        <TraceData>
            <DataItem>
                <MessageLogTraceRecord Time="2016-03-08T11:27:30.7315670+01:00" Source="TransportReceive" Type="System.ServiceModel.Channels.BufferedMessage" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/ServiceModel/Management/MessageTrace">
                    <HttpRequest>
                        <Method>POST</Method>
                        <QueryString/>
                        <WebHeaders>
                            <SOAPAction>"http://notification.services.adyen.com/sendNotification"</SOAPAction>
                            <Content-Length>1140</Content-Length>
                            <Content-Type>text/xml; charset=UTF-8</Content-Type>
                            <Authorization>Basic obscured</Authorization>
                            <Host>obscured</Host>
                            <User-Agent>Jakarta Commons-HttpClient/3.0.1</User-Agent>
                        </WebHeaders>
                    </HttpRequest>
                    <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                        <s:Header xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
                            <To s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">https://obscured</To>
                            <Action s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">http://notification.services.adyen.com/sendNotification</Action>
                        </s:Header>
                        <soap:Body>
                            <ns1:sendNotification xmlns:ns1="http://notification.services.adyen.com">
                                <ns1:notification>
                                    <live xmlns="http://notification.services.adyen.com">false</live>
                                    <notificationItems xmlns="http://notification.services.adyen.com">
                                        <NotificationRequestItem>
                                            <additionalData xsi:nil="true"/>
                                            <amount>
                                                <currency xmlns="http://common.services.adyen.com">EUR</currency>
                                                <value xmlns="http://common.services.adyen.com">10000</value>
                                            </amount>
                                            <eventCode>AUTHORISATION</eventCode>
                                            <eventDate>2016-03-08T11:27:55.572+01:00</eventDate>
                                            <merchantAccountCode>obscured</merchantAccountCode>
                                            <merchantReference>obscured</merchantReference>
                                            <operations>
                                                <string>REFUND</string>
                                            </operations>
                                            <originalReference xsi:nil="true"/>
                                            <paymentMethod>ideal</paymentMethod>
                                            <pspReference>obscured</pspReference>
                                            <reason/>
                                            <success>true</success>
                                        </NotificationRequestItem>
                                    </notificationItems>
                                </ns1:notification>
                            </ns1:sendNotification>
                        </soap:Body>
                    </soap:Envelope>
                </MessageLogTraceRecord>
            </DataItem>
        </TraceData>
    </ApplicationData>
</E2ETraceEvent>
```

**Final update**
I gave up, I saw that the third party can also send JSON posts. I adapted the configuration to use webHttpBinding, converted the example JSON to a datacontract and deserialize the posted message from the OperationContext.Current.RequestContext.RequestMessage.

Comment: What is the error now? The `NotificationRequest` param is `NULL`? What is expected?

Comment: I expect an instantiated NotificationRequest object. Even when I do not fill any field in WCFStorm and execute the service method, there will still be a filled NotificationRequest object.

Comment: When you compare the two requests (from 3rd party, and from wcfstorm) is there any other difference apart from the namespaces ?

Comment: I think we need to discard what WCFStorm thinks, because the proxy built by WCFStorm only reflects the contract supplied by our own WCF Host. Meaning that if we correct the contract decorations to reflect the third party call, WCFStorm will takeover those changes too.